# Is there an elegant way to enable/disable a checkbox based on the status of another checkbox?

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm putting together a UI - users provide some information, and code executes. I've got some checkboxes. I want to enable/disable some of the checkboxes based on the status of other checkboxes. As an example, my UI has a checkbox which lets a user specify if they wanted a file to print, and a checkbox that let a user specify if they want it to print in colour. If the 'print' checkbox isn't ticked, I want to clear and disable the 'colour' checkbox: it doesn't make any sense to let someone say they want to print in colour if they aren't printing.

I can see how to do this with signals/slots, but I'm pretty new to Qt, so I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this. Looking at ButtonGroups was my first port of call, but I couldn't see any way to make it work.

What I have looks something like this. I want to emphasize - this does exactly what I want it to do - I'm just not sure that it's the best way to do it, and I'd like not to hate myself if I come back to the code in a few months with more knowledge. I'd be entirely unsurprised if there were built-in functionality that accomplished my goals.

```
self.first_checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
self.second_checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()

self.first_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(self._handleCheckboxStateChanged)

@QtCore.Slot()
def _handleCheckboxStateChange(self):
    if self.first_checkbox.isChecked():
        self.second_checkbox.setEnabled(True)
    else:
        self.second_checkbox.setEnabled(False)
        self.second_checkbox.setChecked(False)
```

Comment: I think it depends on the size of the state space. What you're doing is fine for the simplest cases. As complexity grows, it becomes easier to overlook combinations, and a state machine makes more sense. You could have a look at the Qt state machine framework and decide whether it's overkill in your situation.

Comment: Thank-you very much! I spent some time and effort making checkboxes exclusive before discovering GroupBoxes (radio buttons weren't a good fit for what I was doing, in terms of look and feel) and wanted to prevent similar duplication of effort. I'll keep state machines in mind as a resource if and when I work on larger projects. In this case, it would certainly be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct, my answer just tries to show other equivalent methods:

1.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.first_checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Print")
        self.second_checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("color")
        self.first_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(
            lambda state: self.second_checkbox.setDisabled(
                state != QtCore.Qt.Checked
            )
        )
        self.first_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(
            lambda state: self.second_checkbox.setCheckState(
                QtCore.Qt.Unchecked
            )
            if not state
            else None
        )
        self.second_checkbox.setDisabled(True)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.first_checkbox)
        lay.addWidget(self.second_checkbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2.

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.first_checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Print")
        self.second_checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("color")
        self.first_checkbox.stateChanged.connect(
            self._handleCheckboxStateChange
        )
        self.second_checkbox.setDisabled(True)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.first_checkbox)
        lay.addWidget(self.second_checkbox)

    @QtCore.Slot(QtCore.Qt.CheckState)
    def _handleCheckboxStateChange(self, state):
        self.second_checkbox.setEnabled(state == QtCore.Qt.Checked)
        if state != QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.second_checkbox.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are there particular advantages/disadvantages to the alternates you suggested?

Comment: @johnharveybc As noted, there are no advantages, only alternatives